# Python "responses" mock - unable to call one URL multiple times

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, mocking

I'm using python `responses` module to mock API response in my tests. The problem is that after the url is registered `responses.add()` it can be called **only once** with `requests.get()`, subsequent calls for the same URL raise an exception.

```py
import requests
import responses

URL = 'http://localhost/abcd'

# Test method
@responses.activate
def get_url(url):
  return requests.get(url)

# Set up URL mock
responses.add(responses.GET, URL, body="A B C D")
```

Now the first call works:

```py
>>> print(get_url(URL))   # <Response [200]>
```

However the same call again fails:

```py
>>> print(get_url(URL))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-responses.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(get_url(URL))
  File "<string>", line 3, in wrapper
  File "test-responses.py", line 10, in get_url
    return requests.get(url)
  File ".../site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/responses.py", line 674, in unbound_on_send
    return self._on_request(adapter, request, *a, **kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/responses.py", line 654, in _on_request
    raise response
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by Responses - the call doesn't match any registered mock.

Request: 
- GET http://localhost/abcd

Available matches:

>>>
```

Is there any way to make the mock URLs permanent and call them as many times as the tests need?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your original code is that `get_url` wrapped with decorator and it creates a new responses context every time when `get_url` is called, but `response.add` register url mock is registered only once - for the first response context.

`@response.activate` decorator intended to be used for test cases.
Here is correct way of using decorator that allows to make requests to same url.

```
@responses.activate
def test_function():
    responses.add(responses.GET, URL, body="A B C D")
    print(get_url(URL))
    print(get_url(URL))

test_function()
```

Using `responses.start() / responses.stop()` allows to make many requests for the same URL.

```
import requests
import responses

URL = 'http://localhost/abcd'

def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)

# Test method
responses.start()
# Set up URL mock
responses.add(responses.GET, URL, body="A B C D")
print(get_url(URL))
print(get_url(URL))
responses.stop()
```

For unit tests I'm using [this](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/31#issuecomment-183261462) mixing code .

BTW Latest `responses` version (0.12.0) has function [assert_calls_count](https://github.com/getsentry/responses#assert_call_count) that allows to check the number of requests to url without exception.

```
assert responses.assert_call_count(URL, 1) is True
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, I don't think so.
I am looking at the source code for `responses` and one thing it does is raise an error for *every* uncalled request, so something like what you describe is incongruous with this kind of setup.

If I was facing this problem, I would make my own `get` function that mocks the response in advance, like this:

```
def mocked_get(url, body="A B C D", params=None, **kwargs):  # I stole the arguments from requests.get
    responses.add(responses.GET, url, body=body)
    return requests.get(url, params=params, **kwargs)
```

and I would use this instead of `requests.get`.